# Integral of quotients of $\sin$ function

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the definite integral
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(\frac{21}{2}x)}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)} dx.$$
Wolfram Alpha says [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%5Cpi%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin(%5Cfrac%7B21%7D%7B2%7Dx)%7D%7B%5Csin(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Dx)%7D%20dx) that the answer is $\pi$. I replaced 21 by other constants and think that in general, $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(\frac{n}{2}x)}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}x)} dx = \pi$ for all odd $n \in \mathbb Z$.

However I have no idea how to approach this problem. I tried substituting $u = x/2$ to simplify the integral a bit to
$$2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(nu)}{\sin(u)}.$$
Then I thought that I could maybe use the identity $\sin(nx) = \sin(x)\cos( (n-1)x) + \sin((n-1)x)\cos(x)$. For instance, since
\begin{align*}
\sin(3x) &= \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x) \\
&= 2\sin(x) \cos^2(x) + \cos^2(x)\sin(x) - \sin^3(x) \\
&= \sin(x)(3\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x))
\end{align*}
the integral would become
$$ 2\int_0^{\pi/2} 3\cos^2(x) -\sin^2(x) dx $$
which I am able to solve:
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^{\pi/2} 3\cos^2(x) -\sin^2(x) dx &= 2[\frac{3}{2}(x+\sin(x)\cos(x)) - \frac{1}{2}(x - \sin(x)\cos(x))]^{\pi/2}_0 \\
&= [2x + 4\sin(x)\cos(x)]^{\pi/2}_0 \\
&= \pi.
\end{align*}
However I don't know how to generalize this approach because the expansion for $\sin(21x)$ would have lots of unwieldy terms. Is there another way to do this problem that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe induction can be used

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263705/compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-2013x-sin-x-dx-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider, from where you left off, $$I_n=2\int\frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin\theta} d\theta, $$ where $n$ is odd.
Noting that $$\frac {\sin n\theta-\sin(n-2)\theta}{\sin\theta}=2\cos(n-1)\theta, $$

We have $$I_n=I_{n-2}+4\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\cos(n-1)\theta d\theta$$
$$=I_{n-2}+0$$ since $n-1$ is even.

Hence $$I_n=I_{n-2}=...=I_1$$ and the value of is last integral is $\pi$

Comment: Why is the second equation true? I can't see how to proceed from $\sin(n\theta) - \sin( (n-2)\theta) = \sin^2(\theta)\cos( (n-2)\theta )  + \cos^2(\theta)\sin( (n-2)\theta ) = \sin^2(\theta) [\cos( (n-2)\theta) - \sin( (n-2)\theta) ]$

Comment: @aras $\sin A-\sin B=2\cos \frac {A+B}{2} \sin \frac {A-B}{2}$

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that identity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the closed form of the Dirichlet's Kernel when N = 10.

$\sum _{n=-N}^{N} $ $e^{-inx}$ = $\frac{sin(\frac{(2N+1)x}{2})}{sin(\frac{x}{2})}$

Integration the series term by term, the terms with positive values of n will cancel the terms with negative ones, and the value of the integral when $n=0$ is $ \int_0 ^\pi e^{0ix} = \pi $, thus $ \int _0 ^{\pi} \frac{sin(\frac{(2N+1)x}{2})}{sin(\frac{x}{2})} dx = \pi $ for any integer value of N.

Comment: Yes, I edited it.