# How do i find this $k$?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, improper-integrals, products

I don't know where my teacher got this monster from . I'd appriciate if you could help me with this.

**Question:** Let 
$$f_n(x)=\sum^n_{r=1}\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}-\cos^2\frac{(2r+1)x}{2}}$$
And
$$g_n(x)=\prod^n_{r=1}f_r(x) $$

and$$T_n=\int^\pi_0\frac{f_n(x)}{g_n(x)}$$

Then $$\sum^{10}_{r=1}T_r=k\pi$$

What is the value of $k$?

**Attempt:** I have not gone far yet. I can see that $\cos^2A-\cos^2B$ ought to be some trigonometric identity like $\sin (A+B).sin(A-B)$ Therefore my $f_n$
 boils down to this:

$$\sum^n_{r=1}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin (nx) * \sin (n+1)x}$$

But how to proceed further?A bit detailing will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sin x=\sin\{(n+1)x-\sin nx\}=?$$

Can you recognize the [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: Yes. Got through defining  $f_n $ and $ g_n$ but idk how to do this $$\int \frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}$$

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263705/compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-2013x-sin-x-dx-space

Comment: Got it. Also @lab would it be wrong if I say that $T_{n+2}-T_n=0$?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh, Have you noticed my second answer there?