# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

For every $odd$ $n \geq  1$ the answer should be $\pi/2$

For every $even$ $n \geq  2$ the possible answers are :

$A )$ $ 1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots + (-1)^{n/2+1}\frac{1}{n-1} $

$B )$ $ 3(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots + (-1)^{n/2+1}\frac{1}{n-1} )$

$C )$ $ 2(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots + (-1)^{n/2+1}\frac{1}{n-1} )$

$D )$ $ \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots + (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n-1} )$

$E )$ $ 1-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}-\cdots - \frac{1}{n-1} $

Does the recurrence $ (n-1)(I_{n}-I_{n-2})=2sin(n-1)x $ help?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I gave n values such as 1,2 and I can only guess the answer, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Try partial integration.

Comment: See htt ps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714706/solving-the-integral-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin2n1t-sin-t-mathrmdt and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263705/compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-2013x-sin-x-dx-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first we note that $I_0=0$ and $I_1 = \frac{\pi}2$.

now, using the trig identity
$$
\sin A - \sin B = 2\sin \frac{A-B}2 \cos \frac{A+B}2
$$
we obtain 
$$
I_{n+2} = I_n + \frac2{n+1} \sin \frac{(n+1)\pi}2
$$
if $N$ is odd, therefore, we have $I_N =I_{N-2}=\dots = I_1 = \frac{\pi}2$.

for even values of $N$, say $N=2M$, we have
$$
I_{2M}= I_0+2\bigg(\frac11\sin \frac{\pi}2 + \frac13\sin \frac{3\pi}2+\dots +\frac1{2M-1}\sin \frac{(2M-1)\pi}2 \bigg) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}
$$

Comment: Brilliant work, thanks!

Comment: interesting result! your 'clue' was very useful

Answer (score 5):

For $n$ even, say $2m$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2mx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx&=\text{Im}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{i2mx}}{\sin(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=2\text{Re}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{i2mx}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

Then, letting $z=e^{ix}$ and using long division reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\text{Re}\left(\frac{e^{i2mx}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\right)&=\text{Re}\left(\frac{z^{2m+1}}{z^2-1}\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}z^{2k-1}+\frac{1}{z-1/z}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \cos((2k-1)x)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Then, substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ we find that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2mx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx=2\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$$

---

If $n=2m+1$, then we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin((2m+1)x)}{\sin(x)}\,dx&=\text{Im}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{i(2m+1)x}}{\sin(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=2\text{Re}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{i(2m+1)x}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

Then, letting $z=e^{ix}$ and using long division reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\text{Re}\left(\frac{e^{i(2m+1)x}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\right)&=\text{Re}\left(\frac{z^{2m+2}}{z^2-1}\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m}z^{2k}+\frac{1/z}{z-1/z}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12+\sum_{k=1}^{m} \cos(2kx)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Then, substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ we find that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2mx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks much for your time/work, I'm in my last year of highschool and it's pretty hard to understand, but one day I will come back to this^^

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  All I did was express $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin)x)}$ as a finite sum of cosine functions and the integrated.  What was the challenging part?